# GNOME extension 'Auto Move Windows' not working on Ubuntu 18.04 for terminal

Tags: gnome-shell, workspaces, gnome-shell-extension

I like to start certain applications onto a new or other workspaces, and I found a guide which says to edit it via dconf editor (as shown below).

[image: screenshot of dconf]

I already rebooted, but it is still opening on the current workspace. Does this work on Ubuntu 18.04?

Comment: How did you install 'Auto Move Windows' in the first place? Also what is the output of the following command in Terminal: `ls /usr/share/applications/ | grep -i terminal`?

Comment: @Joe it is working as expected.. please note that the .desktop file for Terminal..https://imgur.com/f9fS6sC

Comment: i actually tried adding the two `*terminal.desktop` before and it still doesn't work. also tried the `rhythmbox.desktop` it also didn't work

Comment: @pomsky can't remember how i installed it, but `/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/auto-move-windows@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com/` exists, so it's installed?

Comment: I wonder why it's installed as a system extension. Please try to install from its homepage: https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/16/auto-move-windows/ It should get installed locally (in `~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/`) and report back.

Comment: I installed it from ubuntu software.. it worked out of the box..

Answer (score 1):

Seems that there are 2 .desktop files in `/usr/share/applications/` for `Terminal` app and the one executing is `org.gnome.Terminal.desktop` while in dash or with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> shortcut..

[image]

setting this value in dconf `org.gnome.Terminal.desktop` will open the terminal in required workspace.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/iwcEv.jpg